# Recruiting participants: question to screen web designers/developers

Tags: usability-testing, recruitment

To understand the level of expertise of participants for a usability test, I always ask something like "What’s your experience with computers or tablets? Mark all that apply."  The choices are:

- I have used computers at work/school
- I feel disadvantaged by my lack of experience with computers
- I communicate with people using email
- I have used computers to look for information (e.g., library catalogue or books)
- I have used computers to support my learning
- I have used computers to find out about careers
- I have used computers for leisure

**But this time, I really don't want anyone who knows about coding or designing of web apps. What would be a subtle question/answer choice to ask them so I can screen them?**

Comment: "What is your experience with developing computer software?"; "What is your experience with designing web applications?" ... What's wrong with just asking the question you're seeking an answer for?

Comment: I have used computers to design or develop a simple application or website? I'm not sure I understand your difficulties.

Comment: I'm concern that I want to explicitly exclude people who are web devs/programmers and I'm worried they wouldn’t be honest if I asked them directly. I'm giving a great incentive.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a statement that allow people to feel good about themselves?

e.g. "I consider myself as a power user, with experience designing and/or developing websites or apps."

You'll need to tweak the wording a bit more here, since a 2-parter doesn't make a very good question.